# Need help speeding up a calculation

Tags: ios, swift, performance, hash, levenshtein-distance

I wrote a program that generates a md5 hash onto a printed out bill. I want to be able to check the hash against a generated list of hashes. I then use a Levenshtein distance function to figure out which hash has the lowest edit distance from the printed out bill.

Here is my code:

```
func checkIfBillIsLegit(stringToCheck:String) -> Bool {
  for i in 0...((secretWords.count)) {                                 // for loop runs about 5 times
     let hashs = String().generateAll(secretWords[i])                  // create the md5 hashs to check against, returns an array with 50 elements
     for j in 0...(hashs.count) {
        if (stringToCheck.minimumEditDistance(hashs[j]) < 5) {        // Levenshtein distance function
           print("legit")
           print(secretWords[i])
           return true
        }
     }
  }

  print("not legit")
  return false
}
```

I want to be able to run this method multiple times per second. It works now, but it's slightly too slow for what I want to do. Problem is, the generateAll() method is too slow to generate 50 hashes per second. I was thinking of calling generateAll outside of this method, but I can't figure out how I would be able to keep track of the list?

Any help would be appreciated.

generateAll() method:

Comment: How often does the array of `secretWords` change?

Comment: The array of secretWords changes outside of this view controller. We can assume that it never changes.

Comment: So you can calculate your hashes once and store the array of hashes for each word in a dictionary [String:[Hash]].  You can use a lazy property so that the hashes are calculated the first time they are needed.  Alternatively you could calculate the hashes on a dictionary miss, so if words are added to the array, the system will automatically calculate new hashes.  You could also use `NSCache` rather than a dictionary

Comment: Can you write out in code what you're explaining? I'm not 100% sure what you are meaning.

Comment: Can you post the code for `generateAll()`?  There may be something there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `NSCache` to ensure that you only calculate the hashes for a particular word when required.  Typically this will be the first time your function is called, but it could also be if the array of secret words is expanded:

```
var hashCache = NSCache()

func checkIfBillIsLegit(stringToCheck:String) -> Bool {

    for secretWord in secretWords {                                 
        var hashes = hashCache.objectForKey(secretWord) as? [Hash]
        if hashes == nil {
            hashes= String().generateAll(secretWord)
            hashCache.setObject(hashes, forKey: secretWord)
        }

        for hash in hashes! {
            if stringToCheck.minimumEditDistance(hash) < 5 {
                print("legit")
                print(secretWord)
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    print("not legit")
    return false
}
```

If you want to know which "secret word" was the match, then I would change the function to return `String?`:

```
var hashCache = NSCache()

func checkIfBillIsLegit(stringToCheck:String) -> String? {

    for secretWord in secretWords {                                 
        var hashes = hashCache.objectForKey(secretWord) as? [Hash]
        if hashes == nil {
            hashes= String().generateAll(secretWord)
            hashCache.setObject(hashes, forKey: secretWord)
        }

        for hash in hashes! {
            if stringToCheck.minimumEditDistance(hash) < 5 {
                print("legit")
                print(secretWord)
                return secretWord
            }
        }
    }
    print("not legit")
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I still need the index for the hash that had the correct minimum edit distance. How do I get that? Is it hashes.indexOf(hash) ?

Comment: You could probably just change that loop back to a counted loop.  However do you want the index or the word?  If you want the word then the function should probably return `String?` rather than `Bool` and then either return the secret word or `nil`.  Also, it doesn't look like `generateAll` should be an extension to `String`.  At least not implemented in that way `secretWord.generateAll()` would make more sense

Comment: Out of interested, what is the purpose of the minimum edit distance?  Is it to allow for possible keying or OCR errors in the entry of the hash?

Comment: You're right. `generateAll` shouldn't be an extension to string but it's useful to me in other parts of my app. I want the index because I have another array that has identifiers for the hashes in secretWords. And the purpose of the min edit distance is for OCR errors, good guess!